# MS Power point professional 2007 slows then hangs

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm using MS Powerpoint 2007 which is running slow and then it hangs.

In the event viewer I see the following:

> Event officelifeboathang, P1 powerpnt.exe, P2 12.0.6425.1000, P3
>   ntdll.dll, P4 5.1.2600.5512, P5 NIL, P6 NIL, P7 NIL, P8 NIL, P9 NIL,
>   P10 NIL.
>
> The client has sent an activation request to the key management
>   service machine.
>
> Info:
>
> 0xC0020017, 0x00000000, dc01.noritakelk.local:1688,
>   70e3821b-db87-4777-862c-8d9f2d5a3646, 2011/07/22 05:24, 0, 2, 41819,
>   6f327760-8c5c-417c-9b61-836a98287e0c, 5
>
> Hanging application POWERPNT.EXE, version 12.0.6425.1000, hang module
>   hungapp, version 0.0.0.0, hang address 0x00000000.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

More information might help.

Have you applied Service Pack 2 for Office 2007?

Is the problem limited to one presentation or does it happen with several/many/all presentations?

Does the problem always occur at a certain point repeatably, or is it random?